# Eliminar un elemento de un array

Tags: php, php7

¿Hay una manera fácil de eliminar un elemento de un array PHP, Tal que `foreach ($array)` Ya no incluye ese elemento?

Pensé que ponerlo a nulo lo haría, pero aparentemente no.

Comment: Hola Carla, bienvenida a la comunidad. ¿Sería mucho pedir que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía __[mcve]__?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si tiene una matriz indexada numéricamente en la que todos los valores son únicos (o no son únicos pero desea eliminar todas las instancias de un valor particular), puede utilizar simplemente `array_diff()` para eliminar un elemento coincidente, como este:

```
$my_array = array_diff($my_array, array('Remover_valor'));
```

Por ejemplo:

```
my_array = array('Andy', 'Bertha', 'Charles', 'Diana');
echo sizeof($my_array) . "\n";
$my_array = array_diff($my_array, array('Charles'));
echo sizeof($my_array);
```

Esto muestra lo siguiente:

```
4
3
```

En este ejemplo, el elemento con el valor 'Charles' se elimina como puede ser verificado por las llamadas `sizeof()` que informan un tamaño de 4 para la matriz inicial y 3 después de la eliminación.

Answer (score 10):

**A. Si quieres eliminar todas las ocurrencias del valor dentro del array**

Puedes combinar las siguientes funciones de PHP: 
[`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) y [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php)

**En el ejemplo he implementado la función `remover()`:**

[Ver DEMO de las soluciones A y B](http://ideone.com/EdAVOf)

```
<?php
//Caso A. Inicializando valores de ejemplo para probar la función

$arr= array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');

$arr_norojo=remover("rojo",$arr);
print_r($arr_norojo);

$arr_noazul=remover("azul",$arr);
print_r($arr_noazul);

/*
 * Nuestra función usando array_keys() y unset()
 * Devuelve un $arr sin el $valor pasado en parámetro
 */
function remover ($valor,$arr)
{
    foreach (array_keys($arr, $valor) as $key) 
    {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    echo "Removiendo: ".$valor."\n\n";
    return $arr;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Removiendo: rojo
Array
(
    [0] => azul
    [2] => verde
)


Removiendo: azul
Array
(
    [1] => rojo
    [2] => verde
    [3] => rojo
)
```

---

**B. Si quieres eliminar sólo una ocurrencia:**

Puedes combinar `unset()` citado más arriba, con [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search).

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
//Caso B. Inicializando valores de ejemplo para probar la función

$arr= array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');
$arr_norojo=remover_simple("rojo",$arr);
print_r($arr_norojo);

$arr_noazul=remover_simple("azul",$arr);
print_r($arr_noazul);


/*
 * Nuestra función simple usando array_search() y unset()
 * Devuelve un $arr sin la primera ocurrencia del $valor pasado en parámetro
 */

function remover_simple ($valor,$arr)
{
    if (($key = array_search($valor, $arr)) !== false) 
    {
    unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    echo "Removiendo sólo una vez: ".$valor."\n\n";
    return $arr;
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Removiendo sólo una vez: rojo
Array
(
    [0] => azul
    [2] => verde
    [3] => rojo
)


Removiendo sólo una vez: azul    
Array
(
    [1] => rojo
    [2] => verde
    [3] => rojo
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Una forma sencilla es usando la función "unset", supongo que estas trabajando con formato "JSON" ya que es muy usado hoy en día:

La sintaxis:

```
unset($nombre_del_array['clave_del_elemento']);
```

Answer (score 1):

aqui otra solucion, le puede servir a otra persona que este buscando

//borrar elementos del primer array que son iguales a los del segundo array

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4];
$array2 = [4,2,1];
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";

foreach ($array2 as $valor) {
    foreach ($array1 as $valor2) {
        if($valor == $valor2){
            //echo "coincidencia" . "<br>";
            echo "$valor2" . "<br>";
            $borrar=array_search($valor,$array1);
            unset($array1[$borrar]);            
        }   
    }
}
print_r($array1);
```

la salida de esto seria: Array ( [2] => 3 )

Answer (score 1):

Dependerá de la situación en la que estés:

*quiero eliminar un  elemento cuyo índice es conocido*
...

```
unset ($array[$pos]);
```

...

*Lo que quiero es eliminar un valor del array*
En este caso como pueden ser varios puedo localizarlos una opción en buscar la posición de ese valor, como puede haber varios, habrá que iterar
...

```
while ($pos=array_seach($valor, $array))
      unset ($array[$pos]);
```

...